# Retrofit / Sphere Engine API error : undefined reference to `main'

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

```
{"error":"OK","langId":1,
"langName":"C++",
"langVersion":"5.1.1",
"time":0,
"date":"2017-04-03 15:38:19",
"status":0,
"result":11,
"memory":0,
"signal":0,"public":false,
"source":"","output_encoded":"",
"output_type":"text","output":"",
"stderr":"",
"cmpinfo":"\/usr\/lib\/gcc\/x86_64-linux-gnu\/6\/..\/..\/..\/x86_64-linux-gnu\/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':\n(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'\ncollect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status\n"
}
```

I am getting an error, I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong?

API Call :

```
public interface SubmitCodeService {
 @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
 @POST("/api/v3/submissions")
 Call<IdResponse> postCode(@Body JSONObject code, @Query("access_token") String accessToken );

 @GET("/api/v3/submissions/{id}")
 Call<CodeOutputResponse> getOutput(
    @Path("id") Integer submissionId,
    @Query("access_token") String accessToken,
    @Query("withOutput") boolean withOutput,
    @Query("withSource") boolean withSource,
    @Query("withStderr") boolean withStderr,
    @Query("withCmpinfo") boolean withCmpinfo);
 }
```

I am submitting a simple HelloWorld program, I am getting an id back in response, however when I try to get the output, it throws this error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Update : I am able to get it up and running by modifying the code to this :

```
Call<IdResponse> postCode(@Body HashMap<String,String> code, @Query("access_token") String accessToken );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "source":""

It seems that your `postCode` function is not correctly sending the source code. This means no `main` function is defined which causes the error mentioned in your post.

You need to review how you construct the value passed to `code` in `postCode` to see if it matches what the API expects.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I will check it out. Currently I am constructing a jsonObject to pass across language and sourceCode in body. I'll change it to HashMap<String, String>